# Search SQLite DB with timestamp doesn't return expected values

Tags: android, sqlite, time

I have an android app, where I write entries to a DB with essentially (in pseudocode) `db.putLong(System.currentTimeMillis());` when certain events happen.  I'm trying to review the database based on those timestamps.  The following code seems to work when `lookBackHours` is 24, but returns 0 when the value goes up to, say 600 or 700.

```
        long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis() - (ONE_MINUTE*60*lookbackHours);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM WorkLog WHERE dutyDayStart>="+timeStamp, null);
        result.moveToFirst();
        int count = result.getCount();
```

`public static final int ONE_MINUTE = (60*1000);`

The logic is: tag records with timeInMillis.  To find records in a time range, find current time, subtract a certain number of `hours*millisPerHour` (furthest back record I'm interested in), return values where timestamp is > furthest back record I'm interested in.   I don't understand why it isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You're putting long but I'm guessing you reading int from dB? (No code provided for that part). 600-700 lookbackhours hits the max value you can store in 32 bit int, that's why you get 0 back.

Comment: To be precise, 596 is the largest `int` that can be multiplied by 3600000 without overflow.

Comment: @nexus_2006 was this the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an overflow.

Change `int ONE_MINUTE` to `long ONE_MINUTE`
Cange `ONE_MINUTE*60*lookbackHours` to `ONE_MINUTE*60L*lookbackHours`
Make sure `lookbackHours` is long